# Colour between the rings on a python radar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I'm rather new to coding and i'm currently stuck on this problem.
I am trying to shade the region from 0-2 on the radar graph and have been using

```
ax.fill(x_as, values3, color="#757575", alpha=0.3)
```

where i set values 3 as 2.

However, this creates a hexagon rather than a smooth shading from 0-2.

Not sure if there is a simple way of solving this, but any input would be useful!

Cheers

[Current radar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP1jO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you post your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clearly point out where your problems lie (what are your results and what do you expect instead), you are much more likely to get help quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to be sure, but most likely you are only using 6 different values in `x_as` -- the same values you use for your line plots. If instead you use a more densely populated array, say with 100 values, your fill area will appear to be circular:

```
thetas = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
ax.fill(thetas, [2 for i in thetas], color = "#757575", alpha = 0.3)
```

Below a figure with some arbitrary data for the line plots and the above given code for the shaded area:

[image]

Hope this helps.